# User permission with Vue.js Cookie

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my project there are superuser and staffs. And only superuser can delete users. So, I wonder that is it possible to delete user with using cookies?

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: You shouldn't be relying solely on client-side technology to determine the level of access to a user. You can store the user access/role in a [JWT](https://jwt.io), for example, and then on the server side perform another round of validation.

Comment: I used cookie just for otp: `VueCookie.set('token', token.token, '10d');
            VueCookie.set('userhome', token.home, '10d');
            axios.defaults.headers.common['Authorization'] = "JWT " + token.token;
            VueCookie.set('user', JSON.stringify(token.user), '10d');`

Comment: How can I check the user role? should I get user data from cookie first?

Comment: @su-wanKenobi Could you update your question with your relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend using cookies for this. Better use some server-side tech to keep track of your users and their state.
Cookies can be used to keep track of a user's session, but that's it.